# Preload next image in Fancybox2 gallery

Tags: fancybox, image-preloader

I would like to preload the next image in a Fancybox2  gallery, but I don't know if that's possible. I know how to preload and image by creating a new Image() object and setting the src attribute, but I don't know which Fancybox callback should I use.
Does anyone know which Fancybox event is triggered when it starts or it finishes displaying the current image?

So the answer is: simply use 2.0.5 and above to take advantage of the `preload` setting, which preloads 3 images by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fancyBox2 since v2.0.5 has an option `preload` - number of images to preload and it preloads 3 images by default

Comment: There is no option for hiding loading animation, why would you need that? If you wish, you can rewrite `showLoading` method - `$.fancybox.showLoading = function() { /* Your own code */ };`

Answer (score 1):

Fancybox 2 already has image preloading built in. Search the source code for "preload" and you'll see how it works.

The preloader is triggered internally after beforeShow is fired in _beforeShow.