# fancybox 2 ajax content (wait for images to be loaded)

Tags: ajax, image, fancybox

I just try to make fancybox display ajax content including one larger image. that works good so far... I just see that the fancybox is not waiting for the image to be loaded. So at the moment the fancebox is displayed, then positioned, then the image arrived, then resized and positioned again. thats not cool.

Does somebody know how to handle that? 
Thanks in advance,
Florian

Comment: If you are using fancybox v2.0.5+ it includes a `preload` option. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9521306/1055987 If that doesn't help, show your ajax code